# After getResponse the page loads but doesn't redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, 3des

C# Asp.Net Triple-Des

I have two aspx pages in a single project. For trial purposes these two pages are in a single project but in the future they will be on seperate servers.

There's a button on the first page (Default.aspx) and this is the code behind:

```
protected void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    WebRequest req = null;
    WebResponse rsp = null;
    try
    {
        const string uri = "http://localhost:52958/WebSite1/Default2.aspx";
        req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Method = "POST";

        req.ContentType = "text/xml";
        var writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        var post = "<VbDoc><Sicil>a</Sicil>,<AdSoyad>b</AdSoyad>,<SubeKodu>c</SubeKodu>,<SubeAdi>d</SubeAdi>,<Mail>e</Mail>,<Tel>f</Tel></VbDoc>";
        post = Encrypt(post);
        writer.Write(post);
        writer.Close();

        rsp = req.GetResponse();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
        if (rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
    }
}
```

On the second page (Default2.aspx) PageLoad gets activated when I debug and I can read the encrypted data but after page_load the page never gets visible, the old one stays. This is the page load of the second page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
    {
        Page.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        var reader = new StreamReader(Page.Request.InputStream);

        var xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();

        if (xmlData.Length != 0)
        {
            xmlData = Decrypt(xmlData);
            TextBox1.Text = xmlData;
        }
    }

}
```

---If I use Response.Redirect on the first page the second page comes visible but I lose the encrypted data.

---My boss doesn't allow me to use query strings

How can I be able to read the response and show the second page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `session`.

Comment: Try using Server.Transfer. For example refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxa892w.aspx

Comment: pages will run seperate server

Comment: @karamba61 then only one solution, store in db from one page and access from db in another page.

Comment: I solved it with using html post '<body onload="submit()">
    <form  name="tokenForm" method="POST" action="http://examp.aspx">
        <input type="hidden" name ="token" value='<%=lblEncrypted.Text%>' />
        <input type="submit"  id="xxx" value="<%=post%>"/>
    </form>
</body>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved it with html post mechanism. .cs like:

```
protected void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var post = "xml data";
    post = Encrypt(post);
    Label1.Text = post;
}
```

.aspx is like

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
        <asp:Label Visible="False" ID="lblEncrypted"  runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
<body>
    <form  name="tokenForm" method="POST" action="http://localhost:52958/WebSite1/Default2.aspx">
        <input type="hidden" name ="token" value='<%=Label1.Text%>' />
        <input type="submit"  id="btnGonder" value="gonder"/>
    </form>
</body>
```